# Do i have to pay for a second database within the limits of usage in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase Blaze Plan, do I have to pay for the second database if it is within the limits of downloads, uploads, writing to database( OPERTATIONS ) ? and if so how much?

I have contacted firebase and if you are within the limits for all the databases combined you do not pay extra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/), billing in Realtime Database doesn't depend at all on how many database shards you created.  It's billed on storage and bandwidth from the entire thing.  There is no "free tier" applied per shard.

Comment: Well you cannot actually see that it doesnt depend on shards, but you can see that it depends on storage, thanks anyway man!

Comment: You can see that there is no billing per shard, which means you can assume the rates are for the entire thing.  Check the billing calculator section at the bottom.  The only limit per shard is the number of connections, which are not individually billed.

Comment: Ill take your word for it, for now. I sweeped the whole website up and down and couldn't find, the pricing per shard or documentation saying that there is no billing per...

Comment: If you want definitive answers on billing you should contact Firebase support directly, not Stack Overflow.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/